# how can get key value array from "form-data" in asp.net core by [FromForm]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a form that has key value array like this:

[image]

In this array, keys has not started from zero so when I defined Request model for get this array as you can see I can't get any value from this array.

Notice that when I try to send this array from zero key that's work correctly:

[image]

But I need to send this array with that approach because the keys make sense.

Request Model Class:

```
public class Correction
{
    [Required]
    public int theory_exam_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int[] answers { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost("correction")]
public async Task<ActionResult<TheoryExam>> CorrectionTheoryExam([FromForm] Correction correction)
{
    return Ok(correction);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it applies to Asp net core (never tried), bur you can check this post for non sequential indices -> https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: is there any way to implement this issue in other approach?
i'm beginner in asp so I thankful for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach

```
answers.Index = 50
answers[50] = 1
answers.Index = 61
answers[61] = 2
answers.Index = 82
answers[82] = 3
```

[image]